# Many to Many with Multiple Parents in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm not sure the title is correct so let me give an example

Say I have `TableA` and `TableB` classes, and a `History` class.

`History` would just be `id, attribute, old value, new value`.

Each Table would have a many-many relationship with `History`.

Obviously I can create a `tablea_history` and `tableb_history` table to keep track of the relationships.

However I'm going to have 5-10 `TableA/B` type tables and 3-4 `History` type tables so that adds up to quite a bit of simple relationship tables. Is that okay? (In both management and efficiency?) It seems like that would add a lot of extra code.

I could also have a `History` defined by `id, table_name, attribute, old, new` but then I wouldn't know how create nice SQLAlchemy relationships.

TL;DR

I guess I am asking what is the best way to associate a child table to multiple kinds (different classes) of parent tables that lets me not worry about the behind the scenes stuff and just use nice SQLalchemy relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I decided on. I'm not sure if it's the most efficient, but it seems like it should be... Note that `Event` would be `History` and `Device` would be `TableA/B`.

You can use a Mixin like [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/declarative.html#declarative-mixins) to easily add the relationship to all the tables. Then you can modify the primaryjoin property of [relationship()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship) to filter by the table. Example code:

```py
class Event(Base):

    #tablename
    type = Column(Unicode(50), nullable=False, index=True)
    #foreign id
    table_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, index=True)
    attr = Column(Unicode(50), nullable=False)
    old = Column(Unicode(50), nullable=False)
    new = Column(Unicode(50), nullable=False)

class MetadataMixin(object):
    @declared_attr
    def events(cls):
        joinstr = '{0}.id == foreign(Event.table_id) and Event.type == "{1}"'.format(cls.__name__, cls.__tablename__)
        return relationship('Event', primaryjoin=joinstr, backref=cls.__name__.lower())
```

and now we can use that:

```py
class Device(MetadataMixin, Base):
    pass

>>> d = Device()
>>> d.events
[]
```

I'll leave this question open a while longer to see if anyone comes up with a better answer before accepting this answer.